# CMake variable expansion using "@" vs. "${}"

Tags: variables, cmake, expansion

Consider the following:

```
SET(TEST_DIR, "test")
INSTALL(PROGRAMS scripts/foo.py DESTINATION ${TEST_DIR})
INSTALL(PROGRAMS scripts/foo.py DESTINATION @TEST_DIR@)
```

The first `INSTALL` command does not work. The second does. Why is that? What is the difference between those two? I have not found any reference to `@@` expansion except in the context of creation of configuration files. Everything else only uses `${}` expansion.

UPDATE: OK, obvious bug in the above. My `SET()` command has an extraneous comma. Removing it, such that it looks like:

```
    SET(TEST_DIR "test")
```

results in both `@@` and `${}` expansions working. Still wondering (a) what is the meaning of `@@` as opposed to `${}`, and why only the former worked with my incorrect `SET()` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [`configure_file()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:configure_file) command when configuring a file both the `${VAR}` form and `@VAR@` form will be replaced VAR's value. Based on your experience above and some testing I did both forms are replaced when CMake evaluates your `CMakeLists.txt`, too. Since this is not documented I would recommend against using the `@VAR@` from in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Note that when using `configure_file()` you can restrict replacement to only the `@VAR@` form by using the `@ONLY` argument.

Comment: Ok, so it is an undocumented feature. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the @VAR@ syntax is only used when replacing variables with the [configure_file](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) command.

Note that the `configure_file` command allows for an extra option `@ONLY`. Using it you can specify that only the @VAR@'s are replaced, but that the ${VAR}'s are kept.

As an example, this can be useful when generating e.g. a cmake-file which is later to be used with CMake again. E.g. when building your project, the @VAR@ will be replaced when using configure_file. After you distributed your project and someone else uses the generated UseProject.cmake file, the ${VAR}$ entries will be replaced.